# What potential duplicate targets should I know about as a reviewer?

Tags: support, faq, duplicates, canonical-question

We have a few canonical questions on this site, i.e., questions that are often used as a target of duplicate closure or were even specifically designed for this purpose. What are they? Are there any non-obvious use cases?

Also, which of those mentioned hare are good candidates for tagging with [canonical-question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-question)?

Comment: Can we make this more visible to askers?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: We could use [these new features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/255554) (which is something we should do anyway), but keep in mind that this Q&A in its current state are directed at reviewers, not at askers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Graduate Admission and Studies

- [How should I deal with becoming discouraged as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219)
- [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/)
- [How are Ph.D. applications evaluated in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students? Am I likely to get into school X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38237)
- [Graduate school admission with a degree in a different field](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44651)
- [I've been admitted to multiple PhD programs, how should I choose between them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/66926)
- [How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/193773/)

## Career path

- [University rank/stature - How much does it affect one's career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90)
- [Is doing two PhDs a good path?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17232)
- [(How) Can I switch from field X to field Y after getting my PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187461/how-can-i-switch-from-field-x-to-field-y-after-getting-my-phd)
- [What are the criteria for degree revocation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/what-are-the-criteria-for-degree-revocation)

## Publications and Conferences

#### Publishing

- [When should a supervisor be an author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/644)
- [Does one need to be affiliated with a university to publish papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3010)
- [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101)
- [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665)
- [Is my paper under review (or similar) for too long and if yes, how should I react?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88355)
- [Can I predict the fate of my manuscript (from information other than a decision letter)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153925)

#### Predatory Publishers, Conferences, and Services

Questions asking for the reputability of an individual publisher are not suited for this site due to being shopping questions.
However, instead of closing them as such, they can be closed as duplicate of one of the following, which will give the asker sufficient guidance to answer the question themselves.

- [How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83764)
- [How can I determine whether a conference is reputable?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9362)
- [Should I pay for a certificate showing the quality of my manuscript before I submit it to a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/147225)

## Other

- [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90725)
- [How to effectively deal with Imposter Syndrome and feelings of inadequacy: "I've somehow convinced everyone that I'm actually good at this"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765)
- [How can I find an old, obscure, or otherwise inaccessible paper when the usual methods fail?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134634)

---

*Feel free to edit this answer to improve it. Please edit this answer instead of posting another answer.*

Comment: I am not sure [Is it acceptable to ask how a professor would like to be addressed through email?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44245/546) needs to be one. Please consider putting it in Others.

Comment: @scaaahu: I wouldn’t include it. It has been used as a duplicate target once so far and it doesn’t strike me as a question we get asked frequently either.

Comment: There do seem to be a large number of questions about addressing professors....

Comment: @Dawn: Okay, but that’s not exactly what the question suggested by Scaaahu is asking. Do you think it would be a good canonical anyway; if yes why? Otherwise, what question would be? Or do we need a dedicated one?

Comment: I think the answers on this one are pretty good. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12346/how-to-address-a-professor-in-letter Although perhaps a dedicated one could be more comprehensive as a canonical post.

Comment: @Dawn: Please create a separate Meta question for this, asking whether we should use one of the existing questions as a canonical or create a dedicated one.

Comment: Is there a good pointer for mental health issues??

Comment: @ScottSeidman: Do you have any specific issue in mind that gets reiterated frequently?

Comment: depression, anxiety, adhd, ...

Comment: @ScottSeidman: But those are broad topics themselves. For example, there certainly isn’t one anxiety question to end all anxiety questions. This FAQ is for cases we have a bunch of very similar questions that can all be answered by one canonical Q&A or where questions are not suitable for this site and a canonical Q&A helps the asker to help themselves (or similar). I am not saying that there is no potential for canonical Q&As within mental health, but right now I don’t see it.