# Implement "umbrella" question-collections for similar questions?

Tags: feature-request

[This questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175284/how-to-mention-a-paper-with-multiple-authors-on-the-cv) has brought up something that I have thought of before: There are recurring questions tackling the same general question, in this case:

> How to include (whatever) papers in a CV?

A quick search reveals that questions similar to but not a duplicate of the question have already been asked in the past, so there is -- as I would call it -- a "question family" that has the same parent question (including papers in CVs).

So I have wondered this before: would it be beneficial to "collect" such questions with similar topics under an umbrella question link? People searching for an answer to their question could more easily browse existing questions on similar topics. I am familiar with the "related questions" on the right side, but I think this would go beyond that, and should definitely be curated by either moderators or other members of sufficiently high reputation.

Comment: [This](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3824/68109) may be relevant. Such questions are referred as "canonical questions", and [its tag](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-question) shows past suggestions and discussions for various canonical questions that were eventually created.

Comment: So you could open a meta question for the specific canonical question you want to suggest.

Comment: In addition to the tag @GoodDeeds mentioned, https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=canonical is a bit broader and includes additional meta questions that probably should get the canonical-question tag but haven't yet.