# Make list of saved questions accessible during "Duplicate" dialogue

Tags: feature-request

The new feature of organizing saved questions into customizable folders came online a few days ago, and I think it is great. I started a folder of "duplicate targets" for questions that are well, good duplicate target as very similar questions tend to pop up regularly. That list includes canonical questions as well as others.

That being said, I wonder if it were somehow possible to access this list (not this list in particular, but my personally saved list of question) while in the "Close as duplicate" dialogue? It would make the process smoother and faster, as I would not have to open another tab with my list, chose the correct link and paste it into the close dialogue window. As I don't recall the specific phrasing for those questions, it is not that trivial to simply find them by typing a few words into the bar to get suggestions (if it were, I would not need to save questions in the first place).

Comment: If this request gets a good number of upvotes we may be able escalate it to the SE staff (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/300001) for an explanation on how escalation of feature requests works).

Comment: How is this different from "canonical questions"? But I, too, have problems finding duplicates or even knowing they exist, though the sidebar gives some hints.

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/what-potential-duplicate-targets-should-i-know-about-as-a-reviewer

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The OP is probably well aware of that Q&A, but their request is to have the possibility of having a list of saved (the new available feature) links readily available when closing a question as duplicate., without the need of jumping to another page and copying a link.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Exactly.

Comment: This was recently requested on the main meta: [Access to save lists in the close as duplicate modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384968/552049).